# How can I get url params in emberjs component

Tags: ember.js

I am beginner at emberjs, I want to access url params in **component** but don't know how it is done in ember js.

I could get url params in **route** with code below:

```
model(params) {
    this.store.query('ticket', {
        page: {
            number: params.page,
            size: params.size
        }
    });
},

queryParams: {
    page: {
        refreshModel: true
    },
    size: {
        refreshModel: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The quick answer:

You can inject the router into the component where you need it like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { computed: { alias }, observer } = Ember

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  routing: Ember.inject.service('-routing'),
  params: alias('routing.router.currentState.routerJsState.fullQueryParams')
})
```

Here is a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/5ca1f70e103abc0e208562b21b259180?openFiles=templates.tasks.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.display-qp.hbs&route=%2Ftasks%3Fpage%3D2) with this implemented.

The longer answer:

You're using the injecting routing which is private, and using routerJsState.fullQueryParams like that is not really standard practice.

Because a query param is really a property somewhere, if you can make that "somewhere" a service, it would be better, because then you can inject that service into your component instead of routing like we do now. For example page and limit can live on a service and be injected into a controller and component, and would be a nicer solution.

Here is [that solution in a twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b9f5b807b87f9f2a592351012b6f14cf?openFiles=components.display-qp.js%2Ctemplates.components.display-qp.hbs&route=%2Ftasks%3Fpage%3D-1).

The relevant code:

```
services/task-pager.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
 page: 0,
 limit: 3,
 nextPage: function() {
    this.set('page',this.get('page') + 1)
    console.log(this.get('page'))
  },
  previousPage: function() {
    this.set('page',this.get('page') - 1)
  }
})

// controllers/tasks.js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

 taskPager: Ember.inject.service(),

 queryParams:['page', 'limit'],

 page: Ember.computed.alias('taskPager.page'),

 limit: Ember.computed.alias('taskPager.limit'),

 actions: {
   nextPage: function() {
     this.get('taskPager').nextPage()
   },
   previousPage: function() {
     this.get('taskPager').previousPage()
   }
 }
})

//components/display-qp.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  params: Ember.inject.service('task-pager')
})

//templates/components/display-qp.hbs
COMPONENT PARAMS PAGE:{{params.page}}
```